# Handling last byte in huffman compression/decompression

Tags: c++, data-structures, huffman-code

I have a program that produces a Huffman tree based on ASCII character frequency read in a text input file. The Huffman codes are stored in a string array of 256 elements, empty string if the character is not read. This program also then encodes and compresses an output file and then is able to take the compressed file as an input file and does decompression and decoding.

In summary, my program takes a input file compresses and encodes an output file, closes the output file and opens the encoding as an input file, and takes a new output file that is supposed to have a decoded message identical to the original text input file.

My current problem with this program: When decoding the compressed file I get an extra character or so that is not in the original input file decoded. This is due to the trash bits from what I know. With research I found one solution may be to use a psuedo-EOF character to stop decoding before the trash bits are read but I am not sure how to implement this in my current functions that handle encoding and decoding so all guidance and help is much appreciated.

My end goal is to be able to use this program to also completely decode the encoded file without the trash bits sent to output file.

Below I have two functions, encodedOutput and decodeOutput that handle the compression and decompression.

(For encodedOutput function, fileName is the input file parameter, fileName2 is the output file parameter)

(For decodeOutput function, fileName2 is the input file parameter, fileName 3 is output file parameter)

code[256] is a parameter for both of these functions and holds the Huffman code for each unique character read in the original input file, for example, the character 'H' being read in the input file may have a code of "111" stored in the code array for code[72] at the time it is being passed to the functions.

freq[256] holds the frequency of each ascii character read or holds 0 if it is not in original input file.

```
void encodeOutput(const string & fileName, const string & fileName2, string code[256]) {
    ifstream ifile; //to read file
    ifile.open(fileName, ios::binary);
    if (!ifile)//to check if file is open or not
    {
        die("Can't read again"); // function that exits program if can't open
    }
    ofstream ofile;
    ofile.open(fileName2, ios::binary);
    if (!ofile) {
        die("Can't open encoding output file");
    }
    int read; 
    read = ifile.get(); //read one char from file and store it in int
    char buffer = 0, bit_count = 0;
    while (read != -1) {//run this loop until reached to end of file(-1)
        for (unsigned b = 0; b < code[read].size(); b++) { // loop through bits (code[read] outputs huffman code)
            buffer <<= 1;
            buffer |= code[read][b] != '0';
            bit_count++;
            if (bit_count == 8) {
                ofile << buffer;
                buffer = 0;
                bit_count = 0;
            }
        }
        read = ifile.get();
    }

    if (bit_count != 0)
        ofile << char(buffer << (8 - bit_count));

    ifile.close();
    ofile.close();
}

void decodeOutput(const string & fileName2, const string & fileName3, string code[256], const unsigned long long freq[256]) {
    ifstream ifile;
    ifile.open(fileName2, ios::binary);
    if (!ifile)
    {
        die("Can't read again");
    }
    ofstream ofile;
    ofile.open(fileName3, ios::binary);
    if (!ofile) {
        die("Can't open encoding output file");
    }
    priority_queue < node > q;
    for (unsigned i = 0; i < 256; i++) {
        if (freq[i] == 0) {
            code[i] = "";
        }
    }

    for (unsigned i = 0; i < 256; i++)
        if (freq[i])
            q.push(node(unsigned(i), freq[i]));

    if (q.size() < 1) {
        die("no data");
    }

    while (q.size() > 1) {
        node *child0 = new node(q.top());
        q.pop();
        node *child1 = new node(q.top());
        q.pop();
        q.push(node(child0, child1));
    } // created the tree
    string answer = "";
    const node * temp = &q.top(); // root 
    for (int c; (c = ifile.get()) != EOF;) {
        for (unsigned p = 8; p--;) { //reading 8 bits at a time 
            if ((c >> p & 1) == '0') { // if bit is a 0
                temp = temp->child0; // go left
            }
            else { // if bit is a 1
                temp = temp->child1; // go right
            }
            if (temp->child0 == NULL && temp->child1 == NULL) // leaf node
            {
                answer += temp->value;
                temp = &q.top();
            }
        }
    }
  ofile << ans;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change it to `freq[257]` and `code[257]`, and set `freq[256]` to one. Your EOF is symbol 256, and it will appear once in the stream, at the end. At the end of your encoding, send symbol 256. When you receive symbol 256 while decoding, stop.