# How to detect that bit input ended?

Tags: bit, huffman-code

I write LZW/Huffman encoder/decoder. LZW coder sends the number of bits according to its table: if it has less then 2^n elements, it sends n bits. Huffman coder recieve these bits byte by byte and encode them into specific number of bits according to its tree.

So the problem is the last byte can contain less then 8 bits. If i use EOF to detect end of input when decoding i can suddenly get EOF value before actual end of input. And if i send/recieve 4 bytes considering the first one is for sign, i lose 1 bit every 4 bytes.

Should i lose these first bits or there is another better solution i don't know?

Comment: Hang on. Why would there be sign bits? Huffman coding doesn't involve sign bits. Could you show some code? I suspect you have language-specific details leaking into your implementation.

Comment: You need to add 0-7 padding bits to the end to round out the last byte after the last symbol encoded.  When decoding, you end when a symbol ends in that last byte, and discard those 0-7 padding bits, as they are not enough for another symbol.  Sign bits don't enter into it, because everything is treated as unsigned.

Comment: ok, that was dumb of me thinking signed codes won't break anything. thx

Comment: Is this a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55135332/handling-last-byte-in-huffman-compression-decompression ?